# Android ICS loses some input CSS styling on focus

Tags: android, html, css

Found issue while testing Login page in **Android ICS,**

It breaks **CSS** outline styling and here is the screenshot of both **ICS and JB**,
[image]

[image]

I tried the following **CSS** but not yet fixed,

```
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

input{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

and here is the html,

```
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
<input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" style="-webkit-text-security: disc;" required/>
```

How do I get rid of this, please someone locate me the exact fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found the fix, I would like to answer my own question,
I added the below line to input field,

```
-webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
```

i.e.,

```
input{
  -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

Ref: http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-user-modify

Once I added this, the input field outline disappears even in **Android ICS**. Thanks